# char *const argv[] vs char *argv and execv system call

Tags: pointers, execve

```
     int main(void)
        {
            int e;
            char *envp[] = {NULL};
            char *argv[] = {"/bin/ls", "-1",NULL};
            //char *argv[] = {"/bin/ls", "-1",NULL};
            argv[1]= "0";;
            //e =  execve("/bin/ls", argv, envp);
            return 0;
}
```

I have used this code but according to the declaration  of execve it takes second parameter as const pointer to char but i have passed without const yet it is working fine. why????

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can always pass a `char*` to a function that accepts `const char*` which is a compatible/legal assignment. You could of course pass `const char*` argument which is fine, too. But generally, the `const` qualifier in the first argument of `execve` simply says that the function `execve` wouldn't modify it.

Also see this related post: [Why can't I pass a char ** to a function which expects a const char **?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html)